# Lucene parsing inconsistency

Tags: java, kotlin, lucene

I have an inconsistency in trying out Lucene.

- 2 functions below, one uses code to build the query, the other uses the same text as is generated from the query.
- Both executed over the same searcher and Lucene indexes.
- The Lucene "database" consists of a single document with group 5, 10, 15 and 20.
- The single document does contain 'Kotlin' as content

Yet, when I perform the search; the getCodeBased query returns 0 documents; while the getTextBased query returns 1 document.  How is this possible; especially since I used the query text generated from getCodeBased and fed it into getTextBased...

Regards and thanks

```
    private fun getCodeBased() : Query {
        val term1 = Term("contents", "Kotlin")
        val term2 = Term("group", "6")
        val term3 = Term("group", "20")

        val subQuery = BooleanQuery.Builder()
            .add(TermQuery(term2), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            .add(TermQuery(term3), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            .build()

        val query = BooleanQuery.Builder()
            .add(TermQuery(term1), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
            .add(subQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
            .build()

        println(query.toString())

        return query
    }


    private fun getTextBased() : Query {
        val mfq = MultiFieldQueryParser(arrayOf("contents", "group"), StandardAnalyzer())
        val query = mfq.parse("+contents:Kotlin +(group:6 group:20)") // working
        return query
    }
```

Comment: Lucene Versions:
- compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-core', version: '8.3.0'
- compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-queryparser', version: '8.3.0'
- compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-queries', version: '8.3.0'

Comment: Only obvious difference is that there is no StandardAnalyzer to getCodeBased()...  but I cannot see obvious place to "add" it.